# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes while I'm using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I am using Chrome, after some time the system freezes. I don't know why it's happening with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I keep updating my system.

Comment: uninstall chrome an re install from software centre