# Ubuntu 18.04 is freezing randomly. How do I debug this?

Tags: freeze

I'm using a Lenovo Notebook that randomly freezes. When I mean random, it's REALLY random, the machine has been on for a week without freezing, freezing when no apps are opened, freezing when opening three tabs in Chrome, freezing when opening terminal, you get the idea.

I want to know which logs or where can I look to try do debug this. I've already run the Lenovo diagnostics for memory and such and no problems were found.

Comment: Note the exact time of freeze(s). Start with /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Hi had this same problem, until I updated to the latest kernel version 4.19 (I used [these](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/) instructions) then it disappeared. Hope this helps.

Comment: @YassineMarzougui I've installed 4.20.5, still have problems. I just gave up. I'm selling the machine.

Comment: kernel version 4.20.5 didn’t work well for me, and was incompatible with some hardware, I would advice you to try 4.19 and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Same happens to me regularly. I tend to believe that LTS means LONG TERM SHIT

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and at least for me there were 2 problems:

The first one was a problem with my video card, so I had to go to bios settings and uncheck the Switchable graphics option.

And the second one, was related to Chrome using a lot of memory and I had to disable chrome hardware acceleration, take a look a this to see if it helps.

[ubuntnu-18-freeze-while-using-chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054738/ubuntnu-18-freeze-while-using-chrome)

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.
I've faced the same problem that Ubuntu 18.04 freezes from time to time. Ubuntu 18.04 completely froze while I was coding, then sometime later the same happened when I watched a movie it was a problem that was not related with the GPU and had random occurrence. I've found this solution after hours of searching. 
Just run this command and restart your computer.

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

After restarting, verify that the 5.0.0.x generic was installed:

```
uname -a
```

That'll work fine.